# setValue not setting the value of cells in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets Script, cells aren't updating when a value is changed from its original value "A" to "X" then back to "A". I have tried inserting Utilities.Sleep into the function to allow the spreadsheet time to update but this does not change the result.

Here is the code:

(Cell B14 is equal to "A" in the beginning on the spreadsheet)

```
function updater() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  
  var updating = "X"
  
  sheet.getRange("B14").setValue(updating);
    
  Utilities.sleep(5000)
    
  sheet.getRange("B14").setValue("A");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You made a typo : `value1Get = value1` to `value1Get == value1`. Also for multiple updates in the sheet consider `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue, I added the if statement to see if it would work around the issue but it does not. I have now edited the code in the post to not include the if statement and the issue is still present.

Comment: your code is not even in a function. provide full code.

Comment: Formatting of post for '''code was cutting the function off. Apologies.

Comment: Replace `Utilities.sleep(5000)` with `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` and it will work.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!